# Остановка бота discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Стоит задача: нужно при запуске программы запускать бота discord, генерировать ссылку-приглашение и останавливать бота.
Есть ли стандартные (валидные) методы остановки бота? В [API Reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) найти его не удалось =/

---

Упрощённый пример бота:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from settings import ds_token, ds_guild_id

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  guild = discord.utils.get(bot.guilds, id=ds_guild_id)
  guild_info = discord.utils.get(guild.channels, name='info')
  ds_link = await guild_info.create_invite(max_age=86400, max_uses=1, reason="")
  # ds_link используется
  # бота нужно остановить  

bot.run(ds_token)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй такой вариант:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bla bla') # Что-то делаешь
    await bot.logout() # Остановка бота
```

[Ссылка на доки по logout](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=bot#discord.ext.commands.Bot.logout)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь ^ -^